# Giving permissions to apache user

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I've developed a web application that lets the users to upload images and transform them to later download them again transformed. I obviously had to give apache user permissions to the directory where users can upload:

```
$ chown root:www-data uploadFolder
$ chmod 1775 uploadFolder
```

This, gives apache group all permissions, except removing.

The application creates a directory for each user session inside the `uploadFolder` directory with `0700` permissions, and saves the user's images inside.

The `uploadFolder` is inside the application directory.

When the image is uploaded, it is served directly (like a link) to the client.

A crontab job is executing a script every 20 minutes, that checks which sessions are active and removes all files and folders inside `uploadFolder` that doesn't match any active session.

It's working fine since two months ago, but I'm not sure if it could be dangerous for my application, database, or other sites in the same VPS.

Does anybody know the risk of being permissive in this situation?

Is there any alternative to avoid it?

This is my apache site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.itransformer.es
ServerAlias itransformer.es *.itransformer.es
DocumentRoot /siteFolder
<Directory /var/www/itransformer-2.0/web>
   AllowOverride all
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Added this snippet code to Apache site configuration:** (this should avoid reading `.htaccess` files)

```
<Directory /uploadFolder>
   AllowOverride none
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: If the server is shared amongst different apps/users, then anybody who can upload scripts that the webserver can execute has full control over those directories, and can do whatever they want to them.  You can look into things like suphp and the like to force php to run as a specific user.

Comment: Theoretically, users can just upload 3MB file size images to the specific directory, because of validation. How could anybody upload anything else?

Comment: I meant if the server is shared and other people can upload code etc.  all applications on the server run www-data so if there are other applications that you don't control that run as the webserver you need to be mindful. but if you are in control over everything on the server (IE it isn't shared, / you trust ever server (Not application) user, then the risk is minimized.

Comment: I don't see how chmod 1775 denies file removal. If you can write, you can remove as well...

Comment: No, you can't due to sticky bit.

Comment: `AllowOverride all` means a user could potentially upload an `.htaccess` file and rewrite your folder configuration. You probably don't want that.

Comment: I may should add a new `Directory` tag with the uploading folder and add `AllowOverride none`. Am I right?

Comment: If you have full control over your server configuration you should have `AllowOverride none` everywhere in the first place.

Comment: But I'm using `.htaccess` files, and they cannot be acceded without the `AllowOverride all` option. That's why I thought about adding `AllowOverride none` to the `uploadFolder`.

Comment: You should not use `.htaccess` if you have full control over your server configuration. See [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html). Put your rules in a `<Directory>` block of the server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand that security is a process, and you need to keep it in mind at all stages, and at all levels, of your development. Read and understand the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_10#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013) application security flaws and review your code with them in mind, both globally (your whole application) and locally (the individual parts of your application). Of course there are other security flaws so you should document yourself about it.

It is not possible to give good advice on this topic without any code and with only a very general and imprecise description as you are doing here. In your case I would especially watch for [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), XSS, etc, but remember the risk can come from everywhere in your application.

In practice you probably want to [run apache in a chroot jail](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/apache-internal-chroot.html), and I would also upload the folders with some randomly-generated names rather than the name provided by the users (it appears from the updates of your question that you are already doing that indeed). All in all, remember that will just make any flaw you may still have more difficult to exploit, but not prevent them altogether.

Comment: I've never set a chroot jail. Just seen the reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot . Could you post a good reference of how to do this?

Comment: Added a link, it's pretty easy with mod_security, unless you have additional dependences (could be the case with your transformation process).

Comment: I have a problem when trying to show the images. The server cannot access the folder outside the `Document Root`. How should I do this?

Comment: You need to check the permissions on the folder. The script (usually running as the same user as the server, typically `www-data` or `apache`) must have write access to it.

Comment: I  guess I'm wrong when trying to access to a folder outside the server directory. It should be outside the document root but inside the server directory. Isn't it?

Comment: No, as long as your files have the correct permissions your script can access them. It must be able to access (and execute) all parent directories as well. As I understand it is your application (running as the server user) accessing the files. The server won't directly serve files outside a directory with the correct Allow directive, but I don't think it's what you're doing. Please clarify.

Comment: Question updated with apache site configuration.

Comment: That didn't really answer my question: is your application/script serving the file, or is Apache serving them directly?

Comment: The file is served first by the application with an Ajax call. If you want to save the new file, it is served like a direct link to the file. You may want to have a look: http://itransformer.es

Comment: Apparently the Ajax call only returns a link to the image, not the image itself. So the user requests an image like /public/img/usuarios/XXX/XXX.file.EXT?XXX. Does that map directly to your disk or is it served by your application? I suspect the first option because /public/img/usuarios/XXX/ doesn't exist, but you could be rewriting or doing something else... Please clarify what's going on.

Comment: `/public/img/usuarios/XXX/` exists, but you cannot access due to the `Options -Indexes` in Apache configuration. The images are served directly like a link from an existing directory.

Comment: `Options -Indexes` normally triggers a 401 error on an existing directory, not a 404. But never mind, if you now say that the images are served directly and not by your application, then the picture is totally different, and you need define an `Allow` directive to allow the server serving those files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10999/discussion-between-calimo-and-manolo-salsas)